# Getting a setting from Entitlements.plist

Tags: c#, ios, plist

I am trying to add some custom settings in an iOS application.

Entitlements.plist supports custom settings

[image: screenshot]

But I can't find a way to get these setting programmatically.

I tried:

```
var bundle= NSBundle.FromPath ("Entitlements.plist");
```

But bundle is null.
Could you help me, please?

P.S. I use Xamarin studio and C#, but I can read objective-c code.

Comment: what are you talking about do you expect anyone to understand what you are trying to convey  what is `Entitlements.plist` we can't see what you see also read up on how to ask a question

Comment: Okay. I will try to clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not figure out how I can read settings from Entitlements.plist. If someone can tell me how to access to Entitlements.plist please write here.

Instead I added a settings.plist in a root directory of project. 
Code for settings access:

```
        var settings = new NSDictionary (NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource ("settings.plist", null));

        var value= (NSString)settings ["key"];
```